# Unexpected token when using map

Tags: reactjs

While fetching data from an API and rendering it on the screen i am using map method to cycle through the array, but somehow getting 'Unexpected token' in the token and I am unable to figure out what is the issue.

**Getting an error where the map method is defined.**

```
const ShopItems = props => {
    return (
        {
            props.myData.map( (card) => (
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = React.useState([])
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setItem(data);
            })
    }, [])
    return(
        <div>
            <Header />
            <ShopItems myData={item}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to enclose it in `<>...</>`:

```
  return (
    <>
    {
        props.myData.map( (card) => (
            <div className="card">
                <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    }
    </>
)
```

Comment: oh gawd, I missed that big time. Thank you :)

Comment: @c0dz2r20 No problem. I was at first thrown by the description of the error, but then realized you didn't have tags around your map block. `<></>` or `<Fragment></Fragment>` both work equally well.